# NullPointerException - using spinner

Tags: android

I use a spinner in my `ListActivity` and get a `NullPointerException` at `setAdapter` method. I tried to research similar issues on google and stackoverflow and tried their advice but no use. However, this code works in another app of mine.

```
options = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options_array);
Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options);

s1.setAdapter(adapter); // Here is the error
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "You have selected item : " + options[index], 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {} 
    });
```

My spinner xml

```
    <Spinner    
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"    
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:entries="@array/options_array"
        android:prompt="@string/spin_prompt"
        android:background="@drawable/expander_ic_maximized"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_below="@id/name_text"        
        />
```

LogCat

```
05-04 09:23:48.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

05-04 09:23:48.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at com.amannain.android.missedcalls.MissedCallsSpinActivity.runSpinner(MissedCallsSpinActivity.java:31)

05-04 09:23:48.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(343):     at com.amannain.android.missedcalls.MissedCallsSpinActivity.onCreate(MissedCallsSpinActivity.java:21)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you setting the following in your activity where you have defined your spinner 
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   this main.xml should have your spinner component defined with id "spinner1"

Comment: try printing s1. you will come to know what is throwing null.. whether spinner or options

Comment: Thank you Sush. You pointed me in the right direction. Spinner in my case is defined in another xml and not in the setContentView(R.layout.main) i am using in my current activity. Thats why the NullPointerException. I am filling up my ListView using a CursorAdapter and now i shifted my spinner code there.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, **options**);
```

Because your options value is `null`, you get a `NullPointerException`. Check the `options` value.

Comment: I have tried both ways. Loading array values from the XML as well as filling it up through code. Both err out.

options = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.options_array);
  
options = new String[] {"Default","Cambodian","Chinese","Korean"};

Answer (score 0):

These some modification may help you..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, options);

Here instead of ArrayAdapter you can use SpinnerAdapter, Please modify your code and let me know.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the values in the options(which is passed ArrayAdapter)  is going null. Try to view the values of "options" in log-cat.

Comment: that should not be since options values are getting populated from strings.xml and this same code works in my another app.